# Trouble scraping the text from element

Tags: python, selenium

I want to extract the title of a video on yt

This is the code I came up with:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def get_title():
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/head/title')))
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/head/title').text
    return str(element)

def start(word):
    driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query='+ word)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-search/div[1]/ytd-two-column-search-results-renderer/div/ytd-section-list-renderer/div[2]/ytd-item-section-renderer/div[3]/ytd-video-renderer[1]/div[1]/ytd-thumbnail/a').click()

word = input()
start(word)
title = get_title()
print(title)
```

But I just get a blank text...
Could someone help me, ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_title():
    element=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/head/title'))).get_attribute('textContent')
    return str(element)
```

Would be the simple fix to your code to get an invisible element. But you should use driver.title to get the title value.

Comment: it just keep waiting, I think that it does not find the element

Comment: what value did you use for input.

Comment: I get values off mine right now also sometimes the click isn't working so switch over to a wait.

Answer (score 0):

when you load youtube with search, the title comes as youtube - search text and after some seconds youtube plays the first video. so the title changes within few seconds.

try this :

```
def get_title():
    time.sleep(5)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/head/title'))) 
    return driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/head/title').get_attribute("innerHTML")
```